# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
print ("ПРИВЕТ ЭТО ПРОВЕРКА ТВОЕГО РОСТА И ВЕСА ОТ 7 ЛЕТ ДО 12, НОМРА ИЛИ НЕТ? СЕЙЧАС УЗНАЕМ")

one = float(input("ВЕДИ СВОЙ ВОЗРАСТ"))

two =  float(input("ВЕДИ СВОЙ ВЕС"))

three =  float(input("ВЕДИ СВОЙ РОСТ"))


if  (one ==7)(two>=25) and (two<29) (three>=123) and (three<129):
    print("ok)")
```

Comment: а вот что означают вот эти выражения '(one ==7)(two>=25)' почему между скобками нет никаких логических операторов ?

Comment: а как на говнистость кода влияет то, что вы его пишите для себя или для кого-то другого? :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
(two<29) (three>=123)
```

это что за хитрая конструкция?

если нужен был `or`, тогда

```
((two<29) or (three>=123))
```

Ошибка `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` произошла по следующей причине:

`(two<29)` - это `True` или `False` (булев тип), а затем вы еще пытаетесь к нему обратиться как к функции, т.е. вызвать с параметром `(three>=123)`

поэтому и выдается ошибка - что булево значение не вызываемое - True(False) не реализовать

очевидно, что вы просто не добавили между двумя значениями какой-то оператор

Comment: обращение к переменной

Comment: к какой переменной - у вас между двух конструкций отсутствует логическая или арифметическая команда или у вас что-то очень хитрое должно быть?

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ! ВСЕ ИСПРАВИЛ! БУДУ ЗНАТЬ!